# ¿Hay que crear un modelo por tabla o puede haber un modelo para varias tablas?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Dispongo de varias tablas en la base de datos, cada una con unas 500-1000 filas.

- TablaPreguntasMatematicas
- TablaPreguntasCienciasNaturales
- TablaPreguntasCienciasSociales
- TablaPreguntasTecnologia
- TablaPreguntasFisica
- TablaPreguntasQuimica
- TablaPreguntasMusica

La duda es: ¿Puedo crear un sólo modelo por ejemplo llamado "ModeloPreguntas" para todas las tablas, o cada tabla debe tener su correspondiente y propio modelo en Laravel?

Gracias.

Comment: Cada modelo es una representación de cada tabla de tu base de datos, las únicas tablas que creo no deben llevar la creación de un modelo son aquellas intermedias en una relación de muchos a muchos

Comment: Aquí más al respecto de modelos https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#defining-models

Answer (score 0):

Al revisar el manual oficial de Laravel, como ya está preparado para crear de una vez la migración (de la taba), el modelo y el controlador a la vez, es mejor juntar las diferentes tablas de preguntas, en una sola tabla para un solo modelo se encargue de gestionar la tabla de preguntas. (Eso sí, he tenido que añadir una columna en la tabla, llamada "modalidadPregunta" ya que ahora todas las modalidades de preguntas están en una sola tabla).

Al crear ejecutar...

```
php artisan make:model Pregunta -mcr
```

...crea el modelo, el controlador y el archivo de migración.

Gracias.